# Pokémon Go. Username, Password, Screen name and player ID

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokémon Go account has locked me out and I can’t enter. This has happened very recently. Unfortunately, if I sign up as a returning player, I need my username and password, which I forgot. I would be able to get back my username if I entered the player ID and screen name, but I have no clue on what these two words mean! I really need someone’s help!

Comment: Screen name is the name that's used in-game, AFAIK, and ID the name you've always used to sign in with: an email address in all probability.

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up on Google and according to [Pokemon's support website](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us) screen name is only displayed in any public areas of the website (and in Pokemon GO it is used in game publicly so that other players can know who you are), unlike the username that is meant to log into your account. And as for the player ID, you have to generate your own specific player ID by logging into [Pokemon's](https://www.pokemon.com/) website. You can find more info about screen name [here](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000627193-What-s-the-difference-between-my-user-name-and-screen-name-) and about your player ID and how to generate a player ID [here](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001031234-How-do-I-generate-a-Player-ID-). You can also find info about how to change screen name [here](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000192074-Can-I-change-my-screen-name-).

Hope this helps :)